# Running Multiple Python Scripts Using importlib

Tags: python, sql, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, python-importlib

I have one Python script that essentially runs a daily data pulling process that runs 20 scripts within that script. Each of the sub-scripts runs a sql query.

I have the script on a task scheduler, that begins at 3AM and finishes around 2 hours later.

I would like to improve the speed of this script and run all of the scripts simultaneously.

I have looked into threading and multiprocessing, but I am fairly new to these concepts and computer science in general. What is the best way to go about this process?

```py
import os
import sys
import importlib
import pandas as pd

# Key folder names and locations
# Main folder location
daily_data_path = 'Desktop:\\Daily_Data' 

# Login folder name - must be saved in your desktop and must contain a module called login.py
login_folder = 'Login'

# Login folder location
login_folder_path = os.path.expanduser('~') + '\\Desktop\\' + login_folder

# Direct Python to the correct directories
sys.path.append(daily_data_path)
sys.path.append(login_folder_path)

# Function to dynamically import and run each script
def script_import(path_name):

    try:
        importlib.__import__(path_name)         
        run_ind = '1'
    except:
        run_ind = '0'

# List of daily data paths to iterate over
paths = ['script1.Scripts.script1,
         'script2.Scripts.script2,
         ....,
         'script20.Scripts.script20
        ]


for path in paths:

    # Call the script_import function to run the daily data process
    script_import(path)
```

Comment: have you used the library  threading ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use pool of workers from [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) module in order to execute scripts in separate processes. The [Pool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) class provides `map_async` method, which works like built-in `map` function, but executes everything in parallel. The code may look something like this:

```
import importlib
import multiprocessing


def script_import(name):
    importlib.import_module(name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # List of daily data paths to iterate over
    paths = []

    # create process pool
    procpool = multiprocessing.Pool()

    # apply 'script_import' function in parallel
    result = procpool.map_async(script_import, paths)

    # close the pool and wait for processes to complete
    procpool.close()
    procpool.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

As it sound like your sub-scripts can run independently of the main script, I would advice the use of `subprocess.Popen`, e.g.

```
from subprocess import Popen
import sys
cmnds = [... a list of commands to execute ...]
tasks = [Popen(cmnd) for cmnd in cmnds]
result = sum([task.wait() for task in tasks])
sys.exit(result)
```